# How to build a XML Namespace in Groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-namespaces

I have a SOAP XML which I have to build in Groovy. I'm ABAP programmer and I don't know how to this. Can anyone please help me?
Below the code:

```html
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
              xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-' lv_timestamp_id '">
   <wsu:Created>+lv_created+</wsu:Created>
   <wsu:Expires>+lv_expires+</wsu:Expires>
 </wsu:Timestamp>
 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-">
   <wsse:Username>+lv_username+</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">+lv_sb64password+</wsse:Password>
   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">+lv_b64nonce+</wsse:Nonce>
   <wsu:Created>+lv_created+</wsu:Created>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the docs: http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_markupbuilder

Something like this should work.

```
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.'soapenv:Header'{
  'wsse:Security'('xmlns:wsse': 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'xmlns:wsu': "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")     
    'wsu:Timestamp'('wsu:Id':"TS-' lv_timestamp_id '"){
      'wsu:Created'(lv_created)
      'wsu:Expires'(lv_expires)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's another issue too, in which I need to indicate a line from the password tag on the diggest type and another on the Base64Binary type. Would you know how I can do this?

Comment: Do you mean the `Type="xxx"` in the password tag?

Comment: Try this: `'wsse:Password'('Type': 'xyz') { mkp.yield(lv_sb64password) }`